# Is my reimplementation of this C piece in C++ correct?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, language-lawyer

So I originally had this C code:

```
void stub() { /* do nothing */ }

static void (*mlutiplylasttwovalues)() = stub, (*dividelasttwovalues)() = stub, (*modulolasttwovalues)() = stub;

void mlutiplylasttwovaluesconstexpr()
{
    /*do multiply*/
}

void dividelasttwovaluesconstexpr()
{
    /*do divide*/
}

void modulolasttwovaluesconstexpr()
{
    /*do modulo */
}

void switchtoconstantexpr()
{
    mlutiplylasttwovalues = mlutiplylasttwovaluesconstexpr;
    dividelasttwovalues = dividelasttwovaluesconstexpr;
    modulolasttwovalues = modulolasttwovaluesconstexpr;
}

void switchoutofconstantexpr()
{
     mlutiplylasttwovalues = stub;
    dividelasttwovalues = stub;
    modulolasttwovalues = stub;
}
```

The idea was as you can probably tell to have functions that only do something in specific context.

However since I was writing in C++ actually I decided to rewrite it like this:

```
struct basehndl
{
    virtual void mlutiplylasttwovalues()
    {/* do nothing */ }

    virtual void dividelasttwovalues()
    {/* do nothing */ }

    virtual void modulolasttwovalues()
    {/* do nothing */ }
};

struct handlecnstexpr : basehndl
{
    virtual void mlutiplylasttwovaluesconstexpr()
    {
        /* do multiply*/
    }

    virtual void dividelasttwovaluesconstexpr()
    {
        /* do divide*/
    }

    virtual void modulolasttwovaluesconstexpr()
    {
        /* do modulo*/
    }
};

basehndl hndl{};
```

And then instead of `switchtoconstantexpr` and `switchoutofconstantexpr` I will use:

```
hndl.~basehndl();
new (&hndl) handlecnstexpr{};
```

And respectively:

```
((handlecnstexpr *)&hndl)->~handlecnstexpr();
new (&hndl) basehndl{};
```

My question is - is this a valid standard C++ code or if not is there a better C++ way of doing what I'm trying to achieve without using dynamic allocation as originally.

Comment: I am unable to find anything in the C++ standard that guarantees that both classes must have the same size and alignment, so this abuse of placement new is not guaranteed to be defined behavior. The correct, proper, type-safe implementation of this will simply use `std::variant`, and let it worry about type-safety.

Comment: Just make two separate variables, one of type `basehndl` and the other `handlecnstexpr`, and a `basehndl*` pointer that points to one or the other.